# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy blocking glyphicons from Bootstrap in CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, cors

I'm trying to use the glyphicons provided by Bootstrap 3.3.6 but Chrome is blocking the access to them with this error message:

> Font from origin 'http://[::1]' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
   <IfModule authz_core_module>
      Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !authz_core_module>
      Deny from all
   </IfModule>
   <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </IfModule>
   </FilesMatch>
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I editing the wrong `.htaccess`?

I also tried adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` at the beginning of my `header.php` file but that didn't work either. I'm out of ideas.

The folder structure is like this:

```
   application
       controller
       model
       view
           header.php
           index.php
           footer.php
       .htaccess
   system
   assets
       css
       fonts
       images
       js
```

Comment: `http://::1`? If you're loading the site via an IPv4 address, then an IPv6-hosted resource (even if it's the same physical server) would trigger a cross-origin rejection. so if `http://localhost` ends up going out on `http://127.0.0.1`, then there's your problem...

Comment: And how do I fix that?

Comment: quick/easy/dirty? disable ipv6. that or make sure everything goes out via one of the protocols only, not both.

Comment: @Tywele post your htaccess too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue: I didn't set the base_url in the config.php from CodeIgniter. After setting it everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the base URL to your configuration file:

```
$config['base_url'] ='http://www.urlname.com';

We can set this way so we can move any server no need to change try this one.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Allowing cross-site scripting may cause security issues, try to adjust your codeigniter options;**

1.) Go to application/config/config.php file, 
2.) find $config['base_url'] = ""; and 
3.) place your project folder's path as value. $config['base_url']="*http://localhost/yourProjectFolder/*";